# What's wrong with this form? Can't I use two buttons in one form, here? (see detail)

Tags: html, forms, button

In the form given below, I've created two buttons, one is the **submit button**, and other is simple **href button**.

The problem is that, sometimes, when I click href button, it opens the page which is supposed to open by clicking submit button. Submit button works fine. But sometimes this href button creates problem, as it doesn't perform its own action, that is href="#". Instead it works as submit button. What's the problem? How to solve it?

(It's not because of javascript function, I'm quite sure of it).

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="Resultpage.php">
          <p><b>Q.11 Is this a default question?</b></p>
          <p>(A) Yes &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(B) No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(C) Maybe &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(D) Not sure</p>
          <p class="answerbox">
            <input type="text" name="q11" maxlength="1">
          </p>
          <p><b>Q.12 Is this a default question?</b></p>
          <p>(A) Yes &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(B) No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(C) Maybe &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(D) Not sure</p>
          <p class="answerbox">
            <input type="text" name="q12" maxlength="1">
          </p>
          <p><b>Q.13 Is this a default question?</b></p>
          <p>(A) Yes &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(B) No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(C) Maybe &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(D) Not sure</p>
          <p class="answerbox">
            <input type="text" name="q13" maxlength="1">
          </p>
          <p><b>Q.14 Is this a default question?</b></p>
          <p>(A) Yes &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(B) No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(C) Maybe &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(D) Not sure</p>
          <p class="answerbox">
            <input type="text" name="q14" maxlength="1">
          </p>
          <p><b>Q.15 Is this a default question?</b></p>
          <p>(A) Yes &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(B) No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(C) Maybe &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;(D) Not sure</p>
          <p class="answerbox">
            <input type="text" name="q15" maxlength="1">
          </p>
          <button id="backButton" onClick="return messageBack()"><a href="questions2.php">Page 2</a></button><span style="margin-left: 10px"></span><input class="submitanswers2" type="submit" name="subanswer" value="Submit answers and check result"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: you are sure you want to click on the anchor and not the button?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Actually I want both buttons to work. I need both of them, but I don't want the href button to "mix up" with submit button. And I want to click on the buttons. What's the difference?

Comment: does your function `messageBack()` return false or something else

Comment: what does ´messageBack()´ ?

Comment: @abimelex I removed the <a> tag. The function of <a> and messageBack was same, so I removed <a> and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you have an `<a>` inside of a `<button>`.  It seems like you should be able to use one or the other.

However, your underlying problem here is that `<button>` elements without a `type` attribute set default to being submit buttons when they're inside a form.  To prevent the back button from submitting the form, change its `type` attribute:

```
<button id="backButton" onClick="return messageBack()" type="button">
```

Comment: the `<a>` is probably to provide the actual navigation

Comment: @litelite Fine, but it still could be done with just the button or just the anchor.

Comment: Thanks. I added the type and removed the <a> tag and it works fine. Actually I shouldn't have used <a> tag as the JavaScript was also doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have an anchor to go back, and a button to submit.

```
<a class="btn-link" href="previous-page">Go back</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit form</button>
```

It’s not a good idea to navigate back using JavaScript as it’s not going to work 100% of the time; an anchor will.

Comment: I dont think he is navigasting with JS. the `messageBack()`is probably  just a little `confirm()` or else why would there be a link Inside the button?